# How to get HTML content out of Richtext field of Notesdocument

Tags: xpages

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j37pQ.png)Hi In My Xpages application, I would like to take reference of HTML stored in NotesDocument richtext field( Cofiguration document in Notes Client ), so in Xpages data source I mentioned configDoc as source as Notes Domino Document and in Default Action I set it to " Open Document" and in Document id " I set Computed value as below"

```
var vw:NotesView = database.getView("vwConfig")
var doc:NotesDocument = vw.getFirstDocument()
var uniid:String = doc.getUniversalID();
 return uniid
```

In one of the place I placed on computedField property, I mentioned ssjs code as

```
return configDoc.getValue("RTFIeldasHTML").getHTML();
```

this works if I open document but does not work if I open existing document and it gives me an error:

```
Error while executing JavaScript computed expression
docConfig.getValue()' is null
```

Comment: You can’t use an undeclared variable and not use getValue() on a document

Comment: It works on new document, but it does not work if I open existing document. configDoc is declared in Xpages Data source as an opendocument and as document id provided as above computed code

Comment: And what is docConfig?

Comment: See image attached in main post

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j37pQ.png

Comment: So you have two document data sources?

Comment: No Only one configDoc as opendocument and provided uiversal id, I already posted code for document id in the main post. configDoc is being referred  computedField to get richtext content

Comment: there are more documents reference in data source but for config I already explained above

Comment: My basic goal is that I want to refer richtext content of backend document in computedField. as HTML

Comment: You need to provide all code. it is very confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely cause is `docConfig` doesn't have `ignoreRequestParams="true"`. That means it's opening the document whose ID is in the URL and ignore anything you put in the `documentId` property. Set that and it will work correctly.

Comment: Paul you did it, that was the thing it was missing, thanks a ton for this.